# No error shown but JButton and Label can't be seen

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

I'm new to coding and I am facing this problem where it doesn't show the JButton and JLabel that i added in the GUI. What have i done wrong and how do i fix it?

```
    import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

   public class MainMenu {

public static void main (String []args) { 

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Main Menu");
    frame.setSize(480,720);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,5,5));
    JButton meals = new JButton ("Meals");
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("Welcome back!");
    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    panel.add(meals);
    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you `frame.setVisible(true);` before adding any components to it. You should add the components to the frame first, and then, use the `setVisible` method.

```
panel.add(meals);
panel.add(label);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true); //visible after components added
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed version of your code below. Hopefully it works. I tested it in my IDE.

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MainMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
        JButton meals = new JButton("Meals");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome back!");
        panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        panel.add(meals);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setSize(480, 720);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```